# Some Revisions on the Team Pages are showing up blank

Tags: bug, old-teams, revision-history

When you view a [Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/11/socvr) you're a member of, you may notice that you can edit the page. These edits are stored and [viewable](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33615810/revisions) just like revisions to questions and answers on the main site. That is really neat!

However, there appears to be a bug where certain revisions are blank; when I click the `Source` link, it shows me the content fine, so I know it's not lost to history. If you check revisions 5 through 12, when expanded, they just show an extra line of space or two rather than the whole post and any diffs.

The text doesn't appear to be present in the DOM at all; the styles are still there for the divs that are supposed to house the content. There are also no errors in the console (except that Stack Overflow uses an SHA-1 certificate... but that's a different problem)

I found this error in Firefox on Windows 7, and it's been reproduced in [Chrome and Firefox dev on Windows 7 and Linux, respectively](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30114234#30114234). Anyone know what's going on?